# Prime elements of ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-21}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers

Find prime elements of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {-21}]$. Please help with some ideas.

Comment: What approach have you tried?

Comment: The primes in $\mathbb Z$ that are not primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {-21}]$ are those of the form $ x^2+21y^2$. See https://oeis.org/A033215.