# Describe the prime elements of the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers

I have a ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ and I need to describe all the prime numbers of that ring. How I can do that? Thank you

Comment: What definition of 'prime' do you know for rings? Can you give examples of *any* primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830602, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830154, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825742, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829626

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674814/prime-elements-in-mathbbz-sqrt2).